# I want to get as much information i can get to start a new airline who can help me please?

Tags: faa-regulations, airliner, flight-training

I have been researching about the aviation industry and i have some questions about the leasing and buying procedures and faa ,fcc permissions costs, i would really appreciate your help , thank you

Comment: Cost: More money than you have if you can't afford actual paid consultants.

Comment: What is the actual question here? It is great that you have some but this isn't one.

Answer (score 2):

If you were planning your own airline startup, the first thing you would need to ask and answer is "What is my target market"? To answer this question well, you have to look at what the existing aviation industry does, and does not, already provide. Your initial competitive advantage against much larger competitors with economies of scale is going to be the ability to do something that they aren't doing now, and that advantage will be sustainable, thus keeping you in the game longer, if the existing airlines can't or won't do what you will.

The last big U.S. airline startup to remain successful today, JetBlue, was in 2000, and was started by former Southwest employees and execs to create a similar airline with a few more frills up in the Eastern Seaboard. It took hold after a dramatic decrease in competition in the region following 9/11 and the major airline mergers (Northwest with Delta, Continental with United, TWA with American) and the collapse or absorption of several smaller discount lines like Midwest, America West etc. leaving a vacuum at several major airports in the East that the largest surviving discount carrier, Southwest, didn't (at the time) have the fleet size, regulatory approval or low-cost gate rental arrangements to fill.

To start a successful airline, you first have to identify an opportunity like that. That requires in-depth market analysis; how many airlines serve each airport? Where can you go? At what prices? How about nonstops? The information about what flights are available where and at what cost and what amount of rigamarole (stops, layovers) is public and widely available through any travel site. The number of passengers on each flight, and the complete itinerary of each passenger including their ultimate destination, tends to be pretty jealously guarded by airlines to prevent just this kind of data mining by potential competitors.

Having analyzed where people want to go, how they currently get there and at what prices, you might find an opportunity. People in Lubbock and Waco, Texas, for instance, pretty much depend on regional service to Dallas to connect to a larger flight practically anywhere else. You might identify that people in Waco commonly want to get to St. Louis (for whatever reason) but the only available flights are through either Dallas or Houston, nothing direct. If you can offer a nonstop flight at a similar price (or even beat the layover flights) you have yourself a business opportunity. You'll look across the entire map to find more of these, and put together a set of routes that you're confident you could operate profitably. To determine profitability, you'd need to know both the direct and indirect costs of running the route. Fuel, pilot and flight attendant time are your primary direct costs; everything else, from the cost of the aircraft itself, gate rentals, gate staff, ticketing counters and staff, company ground staff, scheduling and administrative staff, corporate floor space, and your own salary is all overhead. You have to reliably estimate all this to determine the allocated cost of running the route, to determine the breakeven ticket price of an 80% full plane, to see whether that price would compete with the airlines currently serving that airport on a similar route.

Using these identified potentially profitable opportunities, you craft a business plan; you'll offer direct service on narrow-body jets, between 50-100 people per flight, between these various under-served cities. These facts will help you determine your basic business needs. First, you need an "Air Operator Certificate". This is actually one of the *last* things you actually receive, once you have at least one plane and a plan to fly it for hire along at least one route, with arrangements for ground support in place at your destinations. To get all those things, you need money. So, you take your business plan, including the plans to purchase the aircraft you'll want to run the routes, and take that to banks and potential investors. Depending on the economy at the time, there's typically a lot of startup investment capital available, however the airline industry has been perceived as extremely risky for at least a decade now, so venture capitalists will be extremely skittish about fronting the millions of dollars needed to buy or even lease a few Bombardiers or Embraers.

Assuming you can pull together the capital you need, you set the plan in motion. You start recruiting pilots with the proper certifications (your flight crewmen will need ATPLs to fly a plane being operated as part of a "commercial airline"; a jet taxi/timeshare business like NetJets can get away with ordinary commercial-level pilots because the business is structured and operated differently), you start hiring ground support and administrative staff, you sign on the dotted line for the plane deliveries, you start making arrangements for bulk fuel purchases at your airports. Eventually all the pieces will fall in to place, your new airline will be issued its AOC and you'll watch your first flight depart the gate with ticketed passengers aboard.

Then the analysis continues; were your estimates correct? Was there demand for your new nonstop route? Did the price you set and the number of customers you got cover the cost of the flight itself and all the other services you needed to get the passengers onto it? If so, pat yourself on the back and continue flying. If not (much more likely), identify what's off. Are you not getting the fuel price you thought because you're small potatoes for the airport's fueling cartel? Did not enough passengers book? Are the pilots or ground crew costing you more than you thought? Can you take these new numbers into account and increase your ticket prices to cover them, or is the problem that you flew a half-empty plane and need to attract more customers to get the per-trip revenues up to your estimates?

Or, did you just fly a brand-new plane full of people who paid more than they otherwise would have, on a non-stop no-frills flight on competitively-priced fuel to another airport with minimum support staff, and still lose money? That's what I thought. That's likely because you set up a network of one or two flights a day out of each airport, for which you still needed to rent time at gates and ticketing counters, and adequately man them both visibly and otherwise. You need to identify more routes you can run, even if the gross margins are smaller, because those additional routes with the same ground staff will make the overhead of running any flights to or from that airport less, making the flights profitable because one flight isn't expected to cover the cost of everything there to support it.

If you can't make it work before the investors cut off the funding, then you go bust. You declare Chapter 7, auction off your assets (planes, ground vehicles, gate/counter facility leases) to the highest bidder, and walk away. You won't be the first nor the last airline in history to have done that.

The actual prices charged by airlines to land each plane, rent a gate, etc are public information but vary by airport (and airlines can negotiate on these fees as they represent a lot of business for the airport). The cost of each plane is also easy to find, as are median salaries for various types of transportation workers (as the companies are often public, so are the CBAs between an airline and various unions). This is all just academic number crunching. The hard part is identifying potential flights with enough customer demand to make operating a flight profitable. The usual way airlines have cut in is to compete directly on price, which is part of the reason the airline industry has until very recently been performing so poorly as an investment; upstart discount carriers flying cheaper fleets to cheaper airports in the same cities have completely destroyed the traditional service-oriented business model.

Comment: I have already chosen a target market, and currently seeing an opportunity like the one you mentioned earlier which is really the reason i wanted to start this, i come from the Dominican Republic , this country has a lot of air passenger growth thanks to tourism which is rising tremendously and the country doesn't have an airline, the routes that fly here are a few but are extremely concentrated and the market is dominated by 3 American carriers making their services really bad and ridiculous prices. where i need help is projecting startup and operating costs

Comment: "The last big airline startup to remain successful today, JetBlue, was in 2000" What, the last in the whole world? Oh, wait. You forgot almost the whole world, unless you're going to claim that, say, Vueling isn't "big" because they only have about half the number of planes that JetBlue has.

Comment: OK, that particular stat was U.S.-centric. There isn't another U.S.-based airline to earn its AOC and grow at the rate JetBlue did since JetBlue, and a large majority of U.S. airlines started since then have shuttered. Vueling and Virgin America (which cheated IMO as it's the U.S. spinoff of the already-successful Virgin Atlantic) are the two most notable of a very short list of airlines started after JetBlue that are still viable at all.